# How to plot China map with South China Sea in base R

Tags: r, gis

I want to get a China map with South China Sea frame as the attach.
The China boundary line and administrative shapefiles can be download from
https://github.com/jimrpy/jimrpy.github.io/blob/master/epidemiology/Archive.zip.

My code is as follows, I don't know how to set the "usr", how to modify the code?

```
library(maps)
library(rgdal)

china_blank <- readOGR(dsn = "~/China/",
                      layer = "China_Province")
china_line <- readOGR(dsn = "~/China/",
                      layer = "China_Boundary_Nineline")

china_blank <- spTransform(china_blank, CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
china_line <- spTransform(china_line, CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))

map(china_blank)
map.axes()   
par(usr = c(73, 136, 0, 54))
rect(xleft = 107, ybottom = 0, xright = 122, ytop = 21, col = "white")
map(china_line, xlim = c(108, 122), ylim = c(0, 21), add =T)
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you want that's different from this?

Comment: @aldo_tapia could you give some suggestion about 'usr'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `usr` graphics parameter defines the area of a system of coordinates that you want plotted, not the area of the canvas where you want the plot. That area is controlled by the `plt` graphics parameter.

For details, see the `help(par)`:

> ```
> (...)
> ‘plt’ A vector of the form ‘c(x1, x2, y1, y2)’ giving the
>       coordinates of the plot region as fractions of the current
>       figure region.
> (...)
> ‘usr’ A vector of the form ‘c(x1, x2, y1, y2)’ giving the extremes
>       of the user coordinates of the plotting region.  When a
>       logarithmic scale is in use (i.e., ‘par("xlog")’ is true, see
>       below), then the x-limits will be ‘10 ^ par("usr")[1:2]’.
>       Similarly for the y-axis.
> (...)
> ```

You can see the current set of parameters by calling `par()` (or, if you only want to see specific parameters, `par(c("plt","usr"))`.

In your case, you seem to want to plot the range given by your rectangle (`xleft = 107, ybottom = 0, xright = 122, ytop = 21`) in the inset, so you will want to define `usr` using these values. With regard to the area of the canvas where you want the plot you may need to experiment a bit. `c(0.76, 0.935, 0.195, 0.45)` works nicely for me, but I am guessing that this may depend on various settings and may be different for you.

In any case, try something like this:

```
par(plt = c(0.76, 0.935, 0.195, 0.45))
par(usr = c(107, 122, 0, 21))
```